# How to avoid LocalStorage overwrite data in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm creating a scheduler in which I can add tasks I've done in a certain amount of time.

Each time I press "STOP" an input appears in in which I can write the task I've just done, and after that the start, end and length of the time that has passed in that timespan get saved.

The main function which I'm trying to fix right now is "addTask()", and I'm trying to store those tasks by using LocalStorage, but each time I add something it gets overwritten instead of being added like a list.

Here's the full code:

HTML:

```html
<div class="modalbox" [class.active]="modalboxActive">
  <div class="modal">
    <p>What did you do?</p>

    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="activity.name" />
    <button (click)="addTask()" [disabled]="activity.name === ''">OK</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="boxSuper">
  <div class="boxLeft">
    <div class="containerUp">
      <button id="start" (click)="startTimer()">START</button>
      <button id="pause" (click)="pauseTimer()">PAUSE</button>
      <button id="stop" (click)="stopTimer()">STOP</button>
    </div>
    <div class="containerDown">
      <p>{{ display }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="boxRight">
    <div class="containerLeft">
      <ul class="listElementLeft" *ngFor="let item of tasks">
        <li>
          <span id="writings">Start:</span>
          <span>{{ item.start }}</span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span id="writings">End:</span>
          <span>{{ item.end }}</span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span id="writings">Length:</span>
          <span>{{ item.length }}</span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="containerRight">
      <ul class="listElement" *ngFor="let item of tasks">
        <li>
          <span id="writings">Activity:</span>
          <span>{{ item.name }}</span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

TS:

```js
import { importExpr } from '@angular/compiler/src/output/output_ast';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { timer } from 'rxjs';
import { Activity } from '../activity';
import { Result } from '../result';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-timer',
  templateUrl: './timer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./timer.component.css'],
})
export class TimerComponent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit() {}
  time: number = 0;
  display: string | undefined;
  interval: any;
  modalboxActive = false;
  startTime: string | undefined;
  endTime: string | undefined;

  activity: Activity = {
    name: '',
  };

  tasks: Result[] = [];

  startFunc() {
    this.startTime = new Date().toString().split(' ')[4];
  }

  endFunc() {
    this.endTime = new Date().toString().split(' ')[4];
  }

  addTask() {
    var el: Result = {
      name: this.activity.name,
      end: this.endTime,
      start: this.startTime,
      length: this.display,
    };
    localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(el));
    window.localStorage.getItem('token');
    this.tasks.push(el);
    this.activity.name = '';
    this.modalboxActive = false;
    this.resetTimer();
  }

  resetTimer() {
    console.log('reset');
    this.time = 0;
  }

  startTimer() {
    console.log('go');
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      if (this.time === 0) {
        this.time++;
      } else {
        this.time++;
      }
      this.display = this.transform(this.time);
    }, 1000);
    this.startFunc();
  }

  transform(value: number): string {
    var sec_num = value;
    var hours = Math.floor(sec_num / 3600);
    var minutes = Math.floor((sec_num - hours * 3600) / 60);
    var seconds = sec_num - hours * 3600 - minutes * 60;
    return hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;
  }

  pauseTimer() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }

  stopTimer() {
    console.log('show');
    this.modalboxActive = true;
    clearInterval(this.interval);
    this.endFunc();
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is enough code to demonstrate the issue, `this.tasks.push` should be adding it to the list, could you try to share more code and/or show specifically what results you've been getting?

Comment: Sure, I'll edit the question.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen here it is.

Answer (score -1):

localStorage simply writes a single object at a single location and maps it to a key, in your case 'token'. Its always going to overwrite what you had.

However, maybe you want to do something more like this:

```
var list = window.localStorage.getItem('token');
list.push(task)
localStorage.setItem('token', list);
```

Comment: I've tried but it doesn't work, could you please show me how you'd add your code inside my typescript instead of separately? Thank you.

Comment: the main thing you need to do, is inside addTask(), you need to first read (getItem) all your tasks from localStorage, then add a new one, and then set them back to localStorage. you are starting with setItem, which is going to wipe out whatever exists.

Comment: Just as a note, localStorage only supports strings so this answer is unlikely to actually work. This needs a JSON.stringify when you set the data and a JSON.parse when you get the item.